Where do career advice questions fit in, in the quant SE?
Specifically, I need opinion/reviews on a quant role I am applying for at a BB firm. The question got put on hold in the main forum, so it looks like its not a valid question over there. Where do I ask my question though? 

This type of question is explicitly off topic on this stack and I’m afraid it doesn’t fit on the Workplace stack either. So to summarize: to my knowledge this type of question doesn’t fit anywhere on Stack Exchange.

Oh, I basically wanted to know if this position allows me access to exit options that align with my future aspirations. Weird that SE doesn't yet accommodate such discussions. Anyway, where else do you reckon I could ask this? I posted on quantnet but couldn't get any response.

Whether this should be on-topic could be discussed on meta. The original reasoning should be stated there to. You could try chat (but unfortunately our chat isn't very active). Outside of Stack Exchange there is the Wilmott forum and LinkedIn.

any specific meta post discussing why? To my knowledge book recommendation (which is as broad as career advice I guess) is fine in other academic sites

Book recommendation questions are fine. The decision to not disallow career advice can be found on Meta.
